# Avoid WordPress header bar when form submission using admin_post in the frontend

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

When form submission is done using `admin_post` in front end,  then in action page header shows WordPress default header bar. How to avoid this header bar

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you want to remove WP admin bar so here you can add `add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false);` in functions.php file.